# Writing in turtle using turtle.write

Tags: python

I need to know how to write words in turtle

I already have tried:

```
turtle.write('world')
```

I expect it to print *world* but it comes with an error.

Here is the error:

> ```
> NotImplementedError: The `write` function is not currently supported.
> ```

I have tried:

```
import turtle
turtle.write('Hi')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: From what little you posted, it appears that you tried to write without providing a `Turtle` object.

Comment: Yes I have done turtle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this as a template:

```
import turtle

turtle.color('deep pink')
style = ('Courier', 30, 'italic')
turtle.write('Hello!', font=style, align='center')
turtle.hideturtle()
```

Just edit the text in the brakets to what you want. Also edit the hello to whatever you want.
Hopes this Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
turtle.write("Hello", font = ("Arial", 12, "bold"))
```

You could take out **"bold"** to have a normal hello. The code is

`turtle.write("Hello", font = ("Arial", 12))`

Answer (score 0):

I know this might seem simple, but have you imported turtle?

If you don't know how imports work, just type `import turtle` at the start of your program.

It should look like this:

```py
import turtle

turtle.write('hello')
```

Comment: what version of python are you running?

Comment: new one from python idle

Comment: what is the name of your program?